# How can I genneration a groovy script loaction by using the payload or header

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I want to use the groovy script, but I want to generate the property `location` by using the value in the headers

How can I achieve this?

```
location="#{scriptService.getScriptLoacation(#headers['location'])}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean in a Spring Integration application.

You can't currently do that; the `location` is a fixed resource.

If you can provide some more context (like what you are using the script for on the message), we might be able to suggest alternatives.